# Value cannot be null Exception in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a Windows Form to create a Employee Card Layout. In addition to that I have added a Button named "Print" which will Print the Panel Content. When I run the code It shows Error when Form loads:
[image: Form Error]

Here is my code:

```
namespace SimpleReport
{
public partial class EmployeeCardForm : Form
{
    //Declare following Object Variables
    PrintDocument printdoc1 = new PrintDocument();
    PrintPreviewDialog previewdlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    Panel pannel = null;

    public EmployeeCardForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //declare event handler for printing in constructor
        printdoc1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printdoc1_PrintPage);
    }

    Bitmap MemoryImage;
    public void GetPrintArea(Panel pnl)
    {
        MemoryImage = new Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
        pnl.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height));
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, 0, 0);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
    void printdoc1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, (pagearea.Width / 2) - (this.panel1.Width / 2), this.panel1.Location.Y);
    }

    public void Print(Panel pnl)
    {
        pannel = pnl;
        GetPrintArea(pnl);
        previewdlg.Document = printdoc1;
        previewdlg.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Print(this.panel1);
    }
  }
}
```

When I debugged the code I came to know that It crashes on first line of OnPaint Event.
Please help me out.

Comment: well you say `Bitmap MemoryImage` and did it occur to you that the paint event fires way long before you click and `MemoryImage` is gotta be null at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MemoryImage` is null before `GetPrintArea()` has been called.

Try this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (MemoryImage != null)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, 0, 0);
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

That's only if you don't want to draw it when it is null. Because it's null initially and then you set it in `GetPrintArea()`. Depending on your circumstance, you could call GetPrintArea() instead of the null check or you could initialise MemoryImage immediately, it all depends on how you want it to  work.

Comment: No worries, as long as it's definitely what you want to do when MemoryImage is null.

Answer (score 0):

You never set your MemoryImage. In your printpage event, before calling DrawImage add GetPrintArea(pnl)

Comment: Did you step through the code to ensure yourself the MemoryImage is being created as intended?